# SQL check a set of elements containing a specific value

Tags: mysql, sql

I Need to write a query to retrieve all the email adresses of customers that have placed and order. Although i need to exclude customers that have ordered the item with productId 1.

Hoever when a customer orderd something with productId 1 and also with a product with a different productId They need to be included. this product with a different productId may also be in a different order of the same customer.

so now i'm kinda stuck with my query.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT [Email] FROM [dbName].[dbo].[Users]

    INNER JOIN dbo.Orders on dbo.Orders.CustomerId = dbo.Users.UserId
    INNER JOIN dbo.OrderLines on dbo.OrderLines.OrderId = Orders.OrderId

    WHERE Users.SubShopID = 1 AND OrderLines.ProductId (continue here?)
    ORDER BY Email DESC
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Email] FROM [dbName].[dbo].[Users]

INNER JOIN dbo.Orders on dbo.Orders.CustomerId = dbo.Users.UserId
INNER JOIN dbo.OrderLines on dbo.OrderLines.OrderId = Orders.OrderId

WHERE Users.SubShopID = 1 
AND OrderLines.ProductId <> 1
ORDER BY Email DESC
```

Comment: but what if one of the orderlines does contain a productid of one and another has a product with an other productid (of the same customer) will the emailadress of this customer also be included (because this has to happen)

Comment: Do you mean within the same Order? Or different orders? If it's different orders, it will be fine, if not, let me know and I'll update my code :)

Comment: Yes they will be included. The query will only exclude customers that have only ever ordered product 1. If a customer has ordered, for example, product 1 and product 2, the product 1 order line will be filtered out but the product 2 order line won't be.

Comment: @weenoid +1 for clarification :)

Comment: different orders is fine. it can be in the same order, or a different order. that doesn't matter. i thought it would be a lot more complicated. thank you very much!

Comment: Ah no problems, glad I could help :)